# Do “for any fixed $x$” and “for arbitrary $x$” differ in meaning?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation, terminology

> Let $f(x,y)$ be a continuous function in $x>1/2$ and $y>3.$
>
> Statement 1: For **any fixed** $x>1/2$ $$|f(x,y)|\leq C y  \ \ \ \ \text{whenever} \ \ \ \ y\geq y_0$$ where $y_0$ is fixed and $C>0$ is a constant.
>
> Statement 2: For **arbitrary** $x>1/2$ $$|f(x,y)|\leq C y  \ \ \ \ \text{whenever} \ \ \ \ y\geq y_0$$ where $y_0$ is fixed and $C>0$ is a constant.

**My question:** Does statement $1$ imply statement $2$? Why do we sometimes use the first statement instead of the second statement?

Comment: By the way, what is $C$? You seem to have neither introduced nor defined it.

Comment: @Ahmad Thanks for pointing it out. $C$ is a positive constant

Comment: Is the question stated correctly? "For any fixed $x$" or "For a fixed $x$"? What's the difference for any fixed x and for arbitrary then?

Comment: @FreeMind The question is "For any fixed $x$".

Comment: These are reformulations of the same statement.

Comment: @QiZhu I don't see any difference between two statements above!

Comment: @FreeMind That's because there is no difference. :D

Comment: @QiZhu Are you sure that these two statements are same? If yes then why we use the first statement instead of the second statement?

Comment: @FreeMind Are you sure that these two statements are same?

Comment: It's just a synonymous way of writing it.

Comment: @QiZhu Thank you so much

Comment: @Shyam Yes. Because the statements, "For any fixed $x$" and "For arbitrary $x$" are equivalent logically.

Comment: @FreeMind But please wait. We have an answer claiming that the statement 1 does not imply statement 2.

Comment: @QiZhu Please see we have an answer saying thay statement 1 does not imply statement 2.

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: If your Question is about the 2 wordings, then it will be simpler to ask **whether "for any fixed x P(x)" is same as "for arbitrary x P(x)" ?** without all the extra unnecessary stuff about "y & f(x,y) & C & 1/2 & 3" ! If you are asking whether one meaning is not same as the other meaning , all the rest is cruft !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Statement 1: For **any fixed** $x>1/2$ $$|f(x,y)|\leq C y  \ \ \ \ \text{whenever} \ \ \ \ y\geq y_0$$ *where* $y_0$ is fixed and $C>0$ is a constant.
>
> Statement 2: For **arbitrary** $x>1/2$ $$|f(x,y)|\leq C y  \ \ \ \ \text{whenever} \ \ \ \ y\geq y_0$$ *where* $y_0$ is fixed and $C>0$ is a constant.

1. When constructing a proof, we might begin by writing

   - Consider **any** (i.e., **an arbitrary**) value of $x$ greater than $\frac12$.

   The idea is that this value is **fixed** when applying the remaining steps, and every time we reiterate the proof's flow of logic, we are free to **arbitrarily** choose **any** value for $x$ and **fix** it for that iteration.

   After we have reached its conclusion, we might summarise the proof, in other words, write its theorem statement, by using [Universal Introduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) to convert the above opening sentence to

   - “**For each** $x{>}\frac12\ldots$”

   So, in each of your given statements, the boldfaced phrase is more clearly and accurately replaced with “*each*”. And since “for $x{>}\frac12$” implicitly means “for *each* $x{>}\frac12$”, the boldfaced phrases are in fact superfluous.
2. The actual problem with your given statements is the potential ambiguity of the word ‘where’: does $$P(x)\text{ is true where }Q(x)\text{ is true}$$ mean $$Q(x)\text{ implies }P(x)$$ or $$Q(x)\text{ and }P(x)\;??$$
3. Here's the best (and safest, given the above ambiguity) rephrasing:

   - For **each** $y_0,$ **each** $C{>}0$ and **each** $x{>}\frac12,$ $$\text{if } \ \ y\geq y_0,  \ \ \ \ \text{then} \ \ \ |f(x,y)|\leq C y.$$

Comment: In my question, will statement 1 imply statement 2?

Comment: @ryang I don't know the answer. Are these two statements equivalent?

Comment: @ryang Ok. Thanks. But why did you say that the boldfaced phrases don't add any meaning?

Comment: I have upvoted. I will accept your answer. Please answer that why did you say that the boldfaced phrases don't add any meaning. I think they are needed

Comment: 1. "for $x>3,\;x^2>9$"$\tag*{}$ 2. "for each $x>3,\;x^2>9$"$\tag*{}$ 3. "let's fix $x$ to be any value greater than $3;$ then $x^2>9$"$\tag*{}$ 4. "let $x$ have an arbitrary value greater than $3;$ then $x^2>9$"$\tag*{}$ @Shyam If these four sentences have identical meanings, then our posts' boldfaced phrases are superfluous. Q.E.D.

Comment: It is superfluous to claim that C is constant & f is continuous ! It is superfluous to include limits 1/2 & 3 ! Will this answer ( to the orignal question by @Shyam ) change if these were not the Case ?? Is it not simply better to get rid of all the cruft and ask only about the Initial few words without all the extra unnecessary words ?? Something about the Question or the Answer is not making sense !!